# Unable to locate element with ID

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, geb

I want to scrape the following website http://condorbus.cl/ 
by GEB but this error appears

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: radio_solo_ida

this the code

```
def browser = params.browser
    browser.drive {
        go "http://condorbus.cl/"

        waitFor(20) { $("div form#ventapasajes").verifyNotEmpty() }
        // Find an element and define it
        WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.id("radio_solo_ida"));
        // Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
        ((JavascriptExecutor)    driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(
                 0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");
        // Click the element
        elementToClick.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting the error I tried locating and clicking on the element with id='radio_solo_ida' and it worked using firefox driver.

That means the **element with id='radio_solo_ida' is present and also uniquely identified** by xpath=//*[@id='radio_solo_ida']

[image]

So the problem maybe related to a particular browser version or synchronization or combination of both I tried using following code for FIREFOX 31.0 and it works:

```
    public class TestRadioButton {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://condorbus.cl/");

        WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.id("radio_solo_ida"));
        // Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");
        // Click the element
        elementToClick.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I use google chrome ,I will try to change to firefox to test ,but I want to solve this bug to use chrome